# HTM CSS fix columns of table with fusion merged cells with horizental scroll

Tags: html, css, merge, html-table, fusion

how can I fix this columns in this table with fusion and merged cells; and add a horizental scroll between them:
[image]

I create a Angular project in stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1ogvc8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css).
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what should be fixed in regards to the columns in the table. But to make it scrollable you can simply set the desired width and `overflow-x:auto`